# Remove lines from one CSV file that is in another CSV file

Tags: csv

I got a CSV file(a.csv) holding about 20k records, and another CSV file(b.csv) holding about 8.5k records.

I want to match a.csv with b.csv, and get a new CSV file(c.csv) holding the 11.5k records that is left. All the records in b.csv is also in a.csv, is this in any way possible?

Best regards

Comment: You could do this in a spreadsheet program like excel or write a short script in any language that lets you access the filesystem. What are you most comfortable with?

Comment: Does excel offer such a functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is using SQL, uploading the DATA to two tables and then make a script to compare the data and write the new resulting data into a FILE.

Comment: Seems a bit comprehensive for such a small task though?